# how to write combined query to access data in asp.net mvc3

Tags: t-sql, ado.net

i am designing a project in  asp.net mvc3, i have designed database in sql server, and i added this in App_Data using ADO.net connection.

this is my ProductFormulation Table

[image]

and this is my RawMaterial table

[image]

now i want to get **Code** from RawMaterial table where ProductID=1 in ProductFormulation.
please tell me what query should i  write. I am using Razor view engine.

Comment: are you writing this in linq.It has no relation with mvc or razor.Please refer to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746                                                                  var res =  (from x in RawMaterial 
                 join y in ProductFormulation on x.ID equals y.ID 
                where y.productID = 1
                select y.Code)

Comment: i appreciate your answer....sir please tell me how can use this "res" in my view(cshtml).? means what coding should i write for print all res ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select rm.Code 
from RawMaterial rm 
    inner join ProductFormulation pf 
        on pf.RawMaterialId = rm.id 
where pf.productid = 1
```

should get you where you need to go

Comment: please write this query which is used in controller class of mvc3.

Comment: i don't know what that means.  you could use that query perfectly well in a mvc 3 controller if you were using ado.net.  if you're not using ado.net, then what are you using.  queries can be written any number of ways, all perfectly valid.  just nhibernate has more than 3 ways to write a query, and thats just the ones that you'd see used frequently.  learn how to program, but if thats too much, learn how to ask a question so you can continue to profit based on the knowledge of others.

Comment: yes sir i am using ado.net. your query is exact right sir. now i want to know how can print this result in my view.cshtml.       I am very sorry sir.

Answer (score 0):

Write in ur controller ->any function

```
var res = (from x in RawMaterial 
join y in ProductFormulation on x.ID equals y.ID where y.productID = 1 select y.Code)
return View(res);
```